# Update table with connected rows

Tags: mysql, sql

OK, I have a table with data like this (MyISAM):

```
This is `table`
    id | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5
    1  | val1   | val2   | val3   | val4   | 1
    2  | val1   | val2   | val3   | val4   | 1
    3  | val2   | val1   | val4   | val3   | 1
    4  | val2   | val1   | val4   | val3   | 1
```

I need to update this table like this (see my `WHERE` clause):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_temp`
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `table`
    WHERE
        `field7` IS NULL
        AND
        `field8` IS NULL
        AND
        `field9` IS NULL
);

UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY IGNORE `table` AS `t`, `table_temp` AS `t2`
SET
    `t`.`field7`=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    `t`.`field9`=`t2`.`id`
WHERE
    `t`.`field1` = `t2`.`field2`
    AND
    `t`.`field2` = `t2`.`field1`
    AND
    `t`.`field3` = `t2`.`field4`
    AND
    `t`.`field4` = `t2`.`field3`
    AND
    `t`.`field5` = `t2`.`field5`
    AND
    `t`.`field7` IS NULL
    AND
    `t`.`field8` IS NULL
    AND
    `t`.`field9` IS NULL
```

After query is done, I have this:

```
This is `table` after query
        id | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 | field9
        1  | val1   | val2   | val3   | val4   | 1      | **3**
        2  | val1   | val2   | val3   | val4   | 1      |
        3  | val2   | val1   | val4   | val3   | 1      | **1**
        4  | val2   | val1   | val4   | val3   | 1      |
```

But I need this (all 4 rows needs to be updated):

```
        id | field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 | field9
        1  | val1   | val2   | val3   | val4   | 1      | 3
        2  | val1   | val2   | val3   | val4   | 1      | **4**
        3  | val2   | val1   | val4   | val3   | 1      | 1
        4  | val2   | val1   | val4   | val3   | 1      | **2**
```

Actually, all 4 rows are affected, but using `IGNORE` is not just a simple keyword, `field9` have `UNIQUE` index.

As I can understand, my query each time starts from the same row in `t2` -> so I have `IGNORE` and **really** affected only 2 rows instead of 4. I mean, when system is about to update 2nd row it looks from the start and the first matching `where` clause is 3rd row -> `IGNORE`, because when system updated 1st row, the first matched row was `id=3`. I need something that would push to next row.

I tried set another `SET`:

```
...
 SET
    `t`.`field7` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    `t`.`field9` = `t2`.`id`,
    `t2`.`field7` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    `t2`.`field9` = `t`.`id`
...
```

but it didn't help me.

Is there anyway to accomplish what I need?

Comment: run the query and check what it returns 

SELECT
    `field7`=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    `field9`=`t2`.`id`
FROM `table` AS `t`, `table_temp` AS `t2`
WHERE
    `t`.`field1` = `t2`.`field2`
    AND
    `t`.`field2` = `t2`.`field1`
    AND
    `t`.`field3` = `t2`.`field4`
    AND
    `t`.`field4` = `t2`.`field3`
    AND
    `t`.`field5` = `t2`.`field5`
    AND
    `t`.`field7` IS NULL
    AND
    `t`.`field8` IS NULL
    AND
    `t`.`field9` IS NULL

Comment: This query returns me 8 rows with `NULL` in each field.

Comment: I guess I should use `TRIGGER` or maybe `PROCEDURE`. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update twice -
1. ascending and then
2. descending

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (
      `id` int, 
      `field1` varchar(4), 
      `field2` varchar(4), 
      `field3` varchar(4), 
      `field4` varchar(4), 
      `field5` int,
      `field7` int,
      `field8` int,
      `field9` int UNIQUE
    )
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `field1`, `field2`, `field3`, `field4`, `field5`)
VALUES
    (1, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 1),
    (2, 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 1),
    (3, 'val2', 'val1', 'val4', 'val3', 1),
    (4, 'val2', 'val1', 'val4', 'val3', 1)
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_temp`
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `table1`
    WHERE
        `field7` IS NULL
        AND
        `field8` IS NULL
        AND
        `field9` IS NULL
   order by id 
);

UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY IGNORE `table1` AS `t`, `table_temp` AS `t2`
SET
    `t`.`field7`=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    `t`.`field9`=`t2`.`id`
WHERE
    `t`.`field1` = `t2`.`field2`
    AND
    `t`.`field2` = `t2`.`field1`
    AND
    `t`.`field3` = `t2`.`field4`
    AND
    `t`.`field4` = `t2`.`field3`
    AND
    `t`.`field5` = `t2`.`field5`
    AND
    `t`.`field7` IS NULL
    AND
    `t`.`field8` IS NULL
    AND
    `t`.`field9` IS NULL
;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_temp2`
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `table1`
    WHERE
        `field7` IS NULL
        AND
        `field8` IS NULL
        AND
        `field9` IS NULL
    order by id desc
);

UPDATE LOW_PRIORITY IGNORE `table1` AS `t`, `table_temp2` AS `t2`
SET
    `t`.`field7`=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
    `t`.`field9`=`t2`.`id`
WHERE
    `t`.`field1` = `t2`.`field2`
    AND
    `t`.`field2` = `t2`.`field1`
    AND
    `t`.`field3` = `t2`.`field4`
    AND
    `t`.`field4` = `t2`.`field3`
    AND
    `t`.`field5` = `t2`.`field5`
    AND
    `t`.`field7` IS NULL
    AND
    `t`.`field8` IS NULL
    AND
    `t`.`field9` IS NULL
;

select * from table1
;
```